# TI ADS1248 24bit ADC app note error

Tags: adc, precision, rtd

I'm looking through the following app note http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau520/slau520.pdf

If we look at page 19 of that pdf, there's the following histogram.
[image]

I'm trying to work backwards to see what voltage they received for the various bins, but I'm not sure if my values are correct.

According to their design, 
Vref = 1.64
Rzero = 120
PGA = 128

The resolution or 1LSB would be \${Vref \over PGA} \over 2^{23} - 1 \$ or ~ 1.52nV

1.52nV * any of the bins = ~ 12mV.

Which to me, seems way to high for this type of circuit. That would translate into 7 ohms off, which is huge in this case. The ideal value we should be seeing is somewhere in the vicinity of 0 because of the Rzero set to 120ohm, it would pretty much cancel the 120 ohm resistor they are using for an RTD.

The only thing I can think of that would make this data make sense, is, if they offset the data by 2^23 -1 to ensure that all bins are positive. I couldn't find anything in any of the pages that would say that this is what they did.

Is my thinking correct that they shifted everything so rather than having a range of +/- 8M, its now just 0 to 16M ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using a [ADS1247](http://www.ti.com/product/ads1247) for the ADC in that app-note.

This is a 24 bit ADC, so the maximum output count is \$2^{24}\$ or 16,777,216. Considering their values are ~8,380,411, which is very close to \$\frac{2^{24}}{2}\$ (which is 8,388,608, so the offset is 8,197).

Based on that fact, I would assume that they're simply doing a improper twos complement conversion, which would effectively do exactly what you describe in the question - shift a range of +/- 8M to 0-16M.

The ADC in question (ADS1247) does not seem capable of producing a non-signed output, so I have no idea how they're getting those values, but they wouldn't make sense unless they're converting their signed readings into unsigned numbers somehow.

---

Basically, I suspect your thinking is entirely correct. What they're showing looks exactly like what you would see if one was improperly converting a signed value to an unsigned value.

Unfortunately, they don't detail the digital end of their test-setup in any way, so there is no way to know for sure.

Comment: Yes, you are right the app note is for ADS1247. The chip  im using is the ADS1248 which share the same datasheet. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Improper twos complement = proper offset binary!